# GitLab ускорить CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Я установил GitLab на свой сервер. Теперь при комите запускается компиляция всего кода на разных платформах, чтобы проверить, что ошибок нигде нет. Все работает через cubernetes GKE.
Но есть одно большое НО. Скачивание и установка всех нужных библиотек занимает больше 4 часов, не говоря уже о том, что и сам репозиторий весит 6ГБ.

Мне хочется сделать так, чтобы все установленные библиотеки (например cmake, gcc, python, mkl, poco...) не нужно было скачивать и пересобирать каждый раз при запуске.

Я знаю, что в GitLab есть **artifacts**, но не понимаю, как через него сохранить что-нибудь.
Если будете писать пример yaml, то напишите что-то простое, например для gcc.

Сейчас мой yaml в упрощенной форме выглядит так. Что подставить вместо вопросиков?

```
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test

linux:gcc:
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  stage: install
  script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt install build-essential -y
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ??

linux:git:
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  stage: install
  script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt install git -y
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ??

linux:build:
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  stage: build
  needs: ["??, ??"]
  script:
    - make
```

Comment: а может докер контейнер один раз приготовить и просто использовать?

Comment: Следует поднять свой docker registry и подтягивать готовый образ для сборки из него.

Answer (score 0):

Артифакты только в пределах `job` передаются автоматически.

Тебе нужно кэши подключить

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/